# 'OPENJSON' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2019 - 15.0.4236.7 (X64)

Compatibility Level is 2019 \ 150

I have a very simple query to transpose some JSON that is stored in a column:

```
SELECT OPENJSON ([fieldname])
  FROM mytable
```

But I keep recieing the error:

```
'OPENJSON' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Do I need to enable something?

Comment: [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is a table valued function, not a scalar function.

Comment: `SELECT cols FROM mytable CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([fieldname]);`

Comment: Alternatively, use `JSON_VALUE` or `JSON_QUERY` if you want to extract a single value or object, respectively.